# ¿Cómo saber todas las casillas de un tablero de ajedrez cuyo vecino también es libre?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero conocer todos los posibles movimientos en un juego de dominación en un tablero de ocho por ocho con la siguiente iniciación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que traté de crear una tabla con Numpy e iterar en ella para comprobar si está libre hacia la izquierda o hacia abajo, en cuyo caso agregamos el par de recuadros. Tengo una classe `Checkerboard` y un `main`

#### Checkerboard

```
import numpy as np

class Checkerboard:

    """checkerboard template"""

    def __init__(self,dimension):
        self.x = np.ones((3,3)) # what does that stands for ?
        self.x = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=int)
        self.dim = dimension
        # warning, [ordinates in reverse,abscisses]
        self.x[1,1] = 1
        self.x[0,1] = 1
        self.x[6,7] = 2
        self.x[6,6] = 2

    def displayCheckerboard(self):
        print("Checkerboard pattern:")
        print(self.x)
```

#### main

```
import numpy as np

from checkerboardW3 import Checkerboard

    def possibleAttempts(cb) :
        # for each row of the 2D array
        print(cb)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # execute only if run as a script
        cb = Checkerboard(8)
        #cb.displayCheckerboard()
        possibleAttempts(cb)
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    possibleAttempts(cb)
  File "main.py", line 7, in possibleAttempts
    for row in cb[0]:
TypeError: 'Checkerboard' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema según el error es que estas iterando sobre una instancia de la clase `Checkerboard`, sin ser esta un iterable ya que no implementas sus métodos `__iter__` y `__next__`.

Tu clase `Checkerboard` tiene un atributo al que llamas `x` que es el `ndarray` sobre el que pretendes iterar. Por tanto, `for row in cb:` no funcionará por lo comentado antes, deberías hacer `for row in cb.x:`. Esto iterará sobre el atributo `x` que es un array de NumPy, y por tanto, iterable.

Lo anterior es lo más simple, no obstante, si quieres iterar directamente sobre tu objeto tienes varias opciones. Además de implementar los métodos `__iter__` y `__next__` en tu clase para hacer los objetos iterables (dado que estás trabajando con NumPy puedes perder eficiencia con esto) puedes hacer que `Checkerboard` herede de `numpy.ndarray`. Esto hace que tu clase tenga los mismos métodos que un array de NumPy pero pudiendo agregar otros propios, así como tus propios atributos. Heredar de ndarray difiere un poco de la herencia común en Python, es un tema algo más complejo pero puedes ver una buena guía con ejemplos incluidos en la documentación de NumPy: [Subclassing ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Este es un ejemplo muy simple basado en tu código:

**checkerboardW3.py**:

```
import numpy as np


class Checkerboard(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, dimension):
        obj = np.zeros((dimension, dimension), int).view(cls)
        obj.dimension = dimension
        return obj


    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self[1, 1] = 1
        self[0, 1] = 1
        self[6, 7] = 2
        self[6, 6] = 2


    def displayCheckerboard(self):
        print("Checkerboard pattern:")
        print(self)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return

        self.dimension = getattr(obj, 'dimension', None)
```

**main.py:**

```
import numpy as np
from checkerboardW3 import Checkerboard

def possibleAttempts(cb) :
    for row in cb:
        print(row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    cb = Checkerboard(8)
    #cb.displayCheckerboard()
    possibleAttempts(cb)
```